# how to fit a navbar inside a dialog page jaquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, navbar

I have try to include a footer with a navbar inside a dialog page, however, the navbar gets bigger than the dialog window.  I did try to just include the navbar without the data-role="footer" but is doing the same.  Looks like the navbar inside the dialog doesn't inherent the css properties from the dialog parent. Here is the code.

```
<div id="addCourse" data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-close-btn="none">
    <div role="dialog">
        <div data-role="header" role="banner">
            <h1>Add course</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content">
             <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="add-course">New course</label>
                <input type="text" name="add-course" id="add-course" placeholder="Enter new course" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="check">Save</a></li>             
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

anybody with sugestions??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the borders on the navbar buttons are not considered when setting width. You can fix it with a little CSS

```
<div id="addCourse" data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-close-btn="none">
    <div data-role="header" role="banner">
        <h1>Add course</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label for="add-course">New course</label>
            <input type="text" name="add-course" id="add-course" placeholder="Enter new course" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="check">Save</a></li>             
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

.ui-dialog-contain .ui-navbar  {
    padding-right: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3125em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3125em;
}
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/2b04g0aa/)**

Answer (score 0):

I did found another way to work around this issue.  I just added a overflow:hidden to the data-role="navbar"

```
            <!-- Dialog Add Course Footer -->
            <div data-role="navbar" style="overflow:hidden;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="delete">Cancel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="ui-icon-fa ui-icon-fa-save">Save</a></li>                
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Dialog Add Course Footer -->
```